# How to use a foreign key to point to a default value without cyclic dependency?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have two models, `service` and `type`. A Service has many many types AND one and only default type.

Using Sequelize I'm trying to do the following

```
// This part is working
Service.hasMany(Type);
Type.belongsTo(Service);

// This part is not
Type.hasOne(Service, { foreignKey: 'defaultTypeId' })
```

The second part causes this error

```
Server start problem :  Error: Cyclic dependency found. type is dependent of itself.
Dependency chain: device -> type -> service => type
```

I understand the error but I cannot find in the documentation a way to do it. Is it possible ? Is it a SQL design problem ? Do you see alternatives solutions ?

I can have a working solution by defining manually `defaultTypeId` in the service model, but it is no longer a foreign key, so I cannot ensure that the type ID exists.

Comment: Maybe you can use Sequelize migrations in order to achieve this? First migration would be to create `Service` table, next create the `Type` table and after that alter the `Service` table by adding the `defaultTypeId` column, which would be a foreign key. In such a case, you would use `constraints: false` when creating relation between models, however the constraint would exist in your database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following

```
Service.hasMany(Type);
Service.hasOne(Type, { as: 'defaultType' })

Type.belongsTo(Service);
```

Comment: This is not working either. It does not add the foreign key constraint and from the doc 
```HasOne inserts the association key in target model whereas BelongsTo inserts the association key in the source model.```

Comment: Yes I tried, but I did not make it work. I also tried by adding `through: Type`